# Drupal view - show translated content and language neutral in same view

Tags: drupal, internationalization, view, multilingual

Is there a way to configure a View to show the current language of a node if it exists alongside all language neutral nodes?

Basically, I have a list of press releases. Only some of them are going to be translated. When I am in the Japanese version of the site, I'd like the Japanese press releases to show if present, otherwise show English.

Answer (score 2):

Sorted it out by adding a Filter to the node for Node translation. Set the filter options to Current language and No language.